# how to authenticate with url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 



<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http,Base64) {
$http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"}; 
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('admin' + ':' + 'admin');
$http({ method : "GET",
    url : "http://10.132.32.212:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/",
    Accept: "application/json",
    withCredentials: true,
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this  is my code but i am not getting any response data .i am thinking that it is not authenticating with the url. can i get any solution

Comment: what is the response? Do you get a 401 status code?

Comment: no i am not getting any thing it is showing me {{my welcome}} expression only

Comment: if you actually see "{{myWelcome}}" in the html page then there is a severe error. Check the consol for errors

Comment: did you check the console network tab?

Answer (score 0):

You used an undefined Base64 service.
I added it as a CDN library.

see

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
```

and the inclusion of the service in the app declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['base64']);
```

results in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 



<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['base64']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $base64) {
$http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"}; 
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $base64.encode('admin' + ':' + 'admin');
$http({ method : "GET",
    url : "http://10.132.32.212:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/",
    Accept: "application/json",
    withCredentials: true,
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/eYJopsNPe8Iqb56arC75?p=preview

Load this code from your server (http://10.132.32.212:8181) and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks for your support,but now also i am not able to get the data.the empty browser is displaying

Comment: Do you mean in the Plunker? That is due to the fact that the script is not loaded from 'your' server (http://10.132.32.212:8181)

Comment: now i am getting xml data can i convert it into json .is there any solution

Comment: Is "http://10.132.32.212:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/" returning XML? If so, can you change the server implementation so it returns JSON instead of XML?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/vis.js"></script>

    <body>

    <div ng-app="list">
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
           
    <div ng-repeat='data1 in data["network-topology"].topology'>
          {{data1["topology-id"]}}
            <div ng-repeat='data2 in data1.node'>
               {{data2["node-id"]}}
     <div ng-repeat='data3 in data2["termination-point"]'>
              {{data3["tp-id"]}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
var app = angular.module('list', ['base64']);
app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $base64) {

   $http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"}; 
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $base64.encode('admin' + ':' + 'admin');

 $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://10.132.32.212:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 }).success(function(tdata) {
   $scope.data= tdata;
  
      });

     });
 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```